# Core Data Fetch GrandChild from Parent

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Thank  you for your help in advance.

I am able to fetch a child entity from a parent, as seen in the code below, but I can not figure out how to fetch the grandchild based on certain on child in a parent.

How do I add on to or change my existing code to get values out of a grandchild based on the child attributes?

```
    NSMutableArray *createdMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor      alloc]initWithKey:@"randomAttribute" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:&sortDescriptor count:2];
    NSMutableArray *sortedResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:   [parentEntity.parentToChild allObjects]];
    [sortedResults sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortedResults valueForKey:@"randomAttribute"];

    NSString *addedCreatedMutable;
    for (int i = 0; [sortedResults count] > i; i++) {
            addedCreatedMutable =  [[sortedResults valueForKey:@"randomAttribute"]objectAtIndex:i];
            addedCreatedMutable =  [addedCreatedMutable stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

            if ([createdMutable containsObject:addedCreatedMutable]) {

            }else{
                    [createdMutable addObject:addedCreatedMutable];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you list the objects and their relationship names? What you're asking is of course possible, but it's a bit hard to grok (for me) from what's above. A couple of suggestions without that;

- You can traverse the relationship from parent to children (not sure if child is a to-many or a to-one though) and again out to the grandchild
- You can get funkier using a `SUBQUERY()` NSPredicate. Advantage is fetch speed, disadvantage is that it's a bit more complex (and sometimes can indicate that you're going about things in not the best way).